# Is there a way to write this more functionally?

Tags: c#, collections, functional-programming

```
static IEnumerable<Tuple<Double, Double>> GetGreatest(List<List<Tuple<double,double>>> lst)
{
    var tempHead = lst[0][0];
    for (int i = 1; i < lst.Count; i++)
    {
        if (i != lst.Count - 1)
        { 
            var previousHead = lst[i - 1][0];
            var currentHead = lst[i][0];

            if (previousHead.Item2 != currentHead.Item1)
            {
                yield return Tuple.Create(tempHead.Item1, previousHead.Item2);
                tempHead = currentHead;
            }
        }
        else yield return Tuple.Create(tempHead.Item1, lst[i][0].Item2);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to write this in a more functional way so I can easier integrate it into projects in other languages like Scala or F#, my issue is that I've been struggling with it for over an hour, and I can't seem to turn it into anything usable, at least not in scala.

**Question:** Could I get some hints that point me in the right direction? So I can un-stuck myself...

**Clarification:** To clear up some possible confusion about naming and such

This is how it's being used:

```
var lst = new List<Tuple<double,double>>{
        Tuple.Create(3.22, 3.29), Tuple.Create(3.22, 4.05), Tuple.Create(3.22, 4.12),
        Tuple.Create(3.29, 4.05), Tuple.Create(3.29, 4.12),
        Tuple.Create(4.05, 4.12),

        Tuple.Create( 9.06, 9.13),Tuple.Create( 9.06, 9.20),Tuple.Create( 9.06, 9.27),
        Tuple.Create( 9.13, 9.20),Tuple.Create( 9.13, 9.27),Tuple.Create( 9.13,10.04),
        Tuple.Create( 9.20, 9.27),Tuple.Create( 9.20,10.04),Tuple.Create( 9.20,10.11),
        Tuple.Create( 9.27,10.04),Tuple.Create( 9.27,10.11),Tuple.Create( 9.27,10.18),
        Tuple.Create(10.04,10.11),Tuple.Create(10.04,10.18),Tuple.Create(10.04,10.25),
        Tuple.Create(10.11,10.18),Tuple.Create(10.11,10.25),Tuple.Create(10.11,11.01),
        Tuple.Create(10.18,10.25),Tuple.Create(10.18,11.01),Tuple.Create(10.18,11.08),
        Tuple.Create(10.25,11.01),Tuple.Create(10.25,11.08),Tuple.Create(10.25,11.15),
        Tuple.Create(11.01,11.08),Tuple.Create(11.01,11.15),Tuple.Create(11.01,11.22),
        Tuple.Create(11.08,11.15),Tuple.Create(11.08,11.22),Tuple.Create(11.08,11.29),
        Tuple.Create(11.15,11.22),Tuple.Create(11.15,11.29),Tuple.Create(11.15,12.06),
        Tuple.Create(11.22,11.29),Tuple.Create(11.22,12.06),Tuple.Create(11.22,12.13),
        Tuple.Create(11.29,12.06),Tuple.Create(11.29,12.13),Tuple.Create(11.29,12.20),
        Tuple.Create(12.06,12.13),Tuple.Create(12.06,12.20),Tuple.Create(12.06,12.27),
        Tuple.Create(12.13,12.20),Tuple.Create(12.13,12.27),
        Tuple.Create(12.20,12.27),
};

var glist = lst.GroupBy(i => i.Item1).Select(i => i.ToList()).ToList(); // creates list of lists

var greatest = GetGreatest(glist).ToList();
```

which in the end (in this case) will produce 2 tuples `(3.22, 4.12)` and `(9.06, 12.27)`

thus in a sense, getting the greatest number in Item2

Note that the data is always ordered sequentially, thus the next item is always going to be bigger than the previous one, thus there's no need for a comparison

**The Purpose** of this mess is to get the first and last number in any non-overlapping group of numbers, so if you look in the collection above, you can see that before the break I have the numbers 3.22, 3.29, 4.05, and 4.12 all of them overlapping in the tuples, in the sense that `(3.22, 3.29)` contains 3.29, which is the first element of the tuple below

what the method does is return a tuple containing the first and last non-overlapping number in each "group" of tuples

The reason I ignore everything but the first item in the sub-list, is because I can see that `Item2` of the first element is the same as `Item1` in the next one (I've written the list so that each line corresponds to a sublist, to make it easier), for that reason there's no reason to include the rest of the list

why then include the rest of the list in the first place you ask? no my choice... this is (a model of) data from a server, it's structured how it is, there's really nothing I can do

what the program does is look for gaps, breaks in the continuation, if it finds a spot where `Item2` does NOT equal `Item1` then it must mean we've found a gap in the data, and we can safely push `Item1` from the first list and `Item2` from the last list prior to the gap, into the tuple we want to yield, thus reducing all the overlapping data to only the important start and endpoints, removing all the in-between bloat.

Comment: The name of the method is `GetGreatest`, but it doesn't really seem to be getting the 'greatest' element of anything... What is it supposed to do?

Comment: `List<List<Tuple<double,double>>>` - consider creating a proper data model.

Comment: By "GetGreatest" what exactly do you mean?  Edit your question to include what you're trying to do, and then how your implementation doesn't meet your desired effect.  Your current implementation doesnt appear to compare values,

Comment: Start by describing what this crazy method is supposed to do, because I can't for the life of me figure it out. It can't be getting the greatest of anything because there are no comparison operators except in the loop condition.

Comment: edited code to clear up confusion

Comment: @ElectricCoffee It's still entirely unclear what this method is supposed to do.  Explain, in English, what your method is supposed to do.

Comment: Your example uses a list, but your method accepts a list of lists.  Your method also appears to ignore all but the first method in each inner list.  Is that intentional?  Why is none of this discussed in your description of the requirements?

Comment: Your explanation only serves to confuse me more.  You need to spend a lot more time explaining this to [that rubber duck](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: 3rd time's the charm, how about now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear that your requirements are as follows:

1. Take the first item from each of the inner lists of tuples; the remaining items in each inner list can be ignored.
2. Group these tuples into groups while the second item of the previous pair is equal to the next item's first value
3. Transform each group into a single tuple containing the first value of the first item and the second value of the last item.

We can now create a method call to perform each one of these individual operations.

```
static IEnumerable<Tuple<Double, Double>> GetGreatest(
    List<List<Tuple<double, double>>> list)
{
    return list.Select(inner => inner.First())
        .GroupWhile((previous, current) => previous.Item2 == current.Item1)
        .Select(group => Tuple.Create(group.First().Item1, group.Last().Item2));
}
```

`GroupWhile` is defined as follows:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GroupWhile<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, T, bool> predicate)
{
    using (var iterator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (!iterator.MoveNext())
            yield break;

        List<T> list = new List<T>() { iterator.Current };

        T previous = iterator.Current;

        while (iterator.MoveNext())
        {
            if (!predicate(previous, iterator.Current))
            {
                yield return list;
                list = new List<T>();
            }

            list.Add(iterator.Current);
            previous = iterator.Current;
        }
        yield return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: hopefully this is easier to translate into scala, thanks!